# div as Circle Showing percentage at the Middle javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vertical-alignment

I Have a div as a circle, with the inner text showing values as percentage say(20%). The problem is the inner text is not displaying exactly at the center of the circle.

The inner text is a dynamic value based on some results in percentage. The radius of the circle is based on the percentage values returned as result.The percentage values returned should be displayed exactly at the center of the circle. Could Someone help me with this.

Thanks.

Heres the code,

```
<style>
    #circle {
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background:blue;
    }
</style>

<div id="circle"></div>  

<script>
    $(function(){
        var maxWidth = 500, // This is the max width of your circle
        percent = Number($('#result').text()); // This is the percentage value
        percent = percent / 100;

        $("#circle").css({
            "width" : maxWidth * percent,
            "height" : maxWidth * percent,
        });
        circle.innerText =$('#result').text() + "%";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `DIV` inside the circle which holds the text and add `position: relative` to `#circle` in the CSS. Also add this:

```
#circle>* {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

`position: absolute` and `top: 50%` / `left: 50%` will place the top-left corner of the inner `DIV` in the middle of the circle. The `transform` shifts it 50% of its own size to the left/top.

Comment: In the case of five circles on the same page showing results?.Could someone help.

Answer (score 0):

This work out for me.

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

You can check the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pallab/zCfyV/embedded/result/